# Why does FSF write that there were only two natural meanings of “free software”?

Tags: meaning

I've recently asked a question about the article https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/open-source-misses-the-point.en.html that was answered with text that answers my question and provides a lot of related information (but I'm not sure if I should close it by accepting the answer), but I have another similar question about it.

The article says:

> The term “free software” has two natural meanings, one of which is the
> intended meaning, so a person who has grasped the idea of “free
> speech, not free beer” will not get it wrong again.

According to a comment to my previous question,

> A natural meaning is a meaning that isn't contrived, artificial, or
> specially constructed for some new purpose.

However, when I searched for “free meaning”, I got (with meanings requiring additional terms removed):

1. able to act or be done as one wishes; not under the control of another.

This negatively correlates with the intended meaning, as probably the freest in this sense software is the co-processor firmware.

- (of a state or its citizens or institutions) subject neither to foreign domination nor to despotic government.

This one indeed gives the intended meaning.

- not a slave.

I don't know if being not a slave of another process is correlated to the intended meaning, but I'd say free software is a slave of its users.

- denoting an ethnic or political group actively opposing an occupying or invading force, in particular the groups that continued resisting the Germans in the Second World War after the fall of their countries.

I don't think all free software does that actively; also, there may be nonfree software that also falls under this definition.

2. not or no longer confined or imprisoned.

If software is only used by its creator, I think it can be thought of confined/imprisoned. Although FSF portraits a iThings as an iPrison, I'd say a sandbox is a jail/prison because the application can't escape it itself.

- not physically obstructed or fixed.

I don't think the obstruction/fixing of software is physical.

- (of power or energy) disengaged or available.

I don't think software being disengaged or available as power or energy has anything to do with the intended meaning.

- not bound in an atom, a molecule, or a compound.

ditto

- denoting a linguistic form that can be used in isolation.

I don't think software can denote a linguistic form.

3. not subject to engagements or obligations.

Almost all software, including free software, is usually subject to its license (in case of GNU GPLv3, it means that you should make all the derivatives GNU GPLv3 and provide information on what you changed); all software that is free in this sense is free in the intended sense, but most free software isn't free in this sense.

- (of a facility or piece of equipment) not occupied or in use.

This one is temporary.

5. given or available without charge.

This positively correlates with the intended meaning, but it's not the intended meaning.

- frank or unrestrained in speech, expression, or action.

See above.

- overfamiliar or forward.

I don't understand this one, but even without it, there are more than 2 natural meanings.

7. (of literature or music) not observing the normal conventions of style or form.

This isn't applicable to software, but it doesn't require additional terms, so I didn't omit it.

8. (of the wind) blowing from a favourable direction to the side or aft of a vessel.

ditto

That's what Google gives, but a Brave search also gives more than two natural meanings for “free software”.

Why did FSF state there were only two?

Comment: This is about English here and I do not know what FSF is, without guessing.

Comment: This seems to "miss the point" entirely.  In fact what is the point?

Comment: @Lambie - the Free Software Foundation.

Answer (score 1):

There might be many meanings of 'free' in the dictionary, but not all could apply to 'software'. 'Free' as in having freedom and not being enslaved is something that could only really apply to a living being and so could not easily apply to software code.

The contrast of *free speech* with *free beer* is a famous analogy in the software world and the purpose of it is to clear up a common misconception about open-source software. The analogy was made by Richard Stallman, founder of the GNU project. It wasn't meant to exhaustively define the word 'free'. He merely aimed to point out that that open source software is not 'free' in the sense that it is distributed without cost - there are models to legally charge for distributing open source software AND it is possible to commercially market your own software while keeping it open source. He then explained that it was 'free' in the sense that it was 'open' and the code can be obtained uncompiled. The scope of the quotation is just these two definitions.

Comment: “'Free' as in having freedom and not being enslaved”, as I understand, is just free as in freedom in any case, so I don't think that's right

Comment: Can you please elaborate more on this by specifying, for each meaning in my question (except, of course, for the last two (I've already done that for them) and the two that do), why it doesn't apply?

Comment: @Orisphera No. I've been quite clear that this quotation is widely known and understood to be about just two definitions - one that is often mistakenly applied (without cost) and the correct meaning (open). This quotation about open-source software is credited to Richard Stallman, the founder of the GNU project. He was not making a statement about how many definitions of the word 'free' there are. Going through each one would be folly.

Comment: What meaning of “folly” do you mean? Either way, I don't think it would be folly

Comment: @Orisphera I'm starting to think your question is off-topic. It has had downvotes and closure votes already. You seem to want to prove something that is outside the scope of the quotation.